# PHP product listing advice

Tags: php, grid

i will try to explain my problem but my English is bad so i hope you will understand me.

Currently, when i add products in admin page they are displayed one next to other in one line, for example, if I add 10 products i have to scroll page to the right to see them all.

Now I want to display them in a grid of 5 products. So, when i add products, five of them are displayed in one line, then the sixth product is displayed underneath the 1st product and so on. I really need this fast, so every help would be useful, and thank you for every answer.

Here is the code

```
<?php 
include "storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php"; 
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT 10");
$productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
if ($productCount > 0) {
echo"<table width='100%' border='0' cellspacing='5' cellpadding='6'>";
   echo "<tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
        $id = $row["id"];
$product_name = $row["product_name"];
$price = $row["price"];
$date_added = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["date_added"]));

    $count = 0;   
    if($count == 5) {
            $count = 0;                     
            echo "</tr> <tr>";       
    }
     echo "<td width='17%' valign='top'><a href='product.php?id=" . $id . "'><img              `enter code here`style='border:#666 1px solid;' src='inventory_images/" . $id . ".jpg' `enter code here`alt='" . $product_name . "' width='77' height='102' border='1' />     </a>`enter code here`</td>";
       echo "<td width='83%' valign='top'>" . $product_name . "<br />
       $" . $price . "<br />";
       echo "<a href='product.php?id=" . $id . "'>View Product Details</a></td>"; 

}

}else {
echo "We have no products listed in our store yet";
}

   echo"</tr>";
 echo"</table>";
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: can we see the generated HTML code

Answer (score 0):

declare `$count=1;` out side `while` loop

use like this

```
if($count % 5==0) {                     
        echo "</tr> <tr>";       
}
```

and before end of while loop increment `$count++`

Comment: Thank you for answer but i can't make this work. I am complete begginer in php, this code is done with some tutorial, so if is not problem for you to put your code in mine and paste everything here, maybe i just not doing that properly. And thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

```
   if ($productCount > 0) {
echo"<table width='100%' border='0' cellspacing='5' cellpadding='6'>";

    $count = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
            echo "<tr>";
    $id = $row["id"];
    $product_name = $row["product_name"];
    $price = $row["price"];
    $date_added = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["date_added"]));
    echo "<td width='17%' valign='top'><a href='product.php?id=" . $id . "'><img style='border:#666 1px solid;' src='inventory_images/" . $id . ".jpg' `enter code here`alt='" . $product_name . "' width='77' height='102' border='1' />     </a>`enter code here`</td>";
    echo "<td width='83%' valign='top'>" . $product_name . "<br />
   $" . $price . "<br />";
    echo "<a href='product.php?id=" . $id . "'>View Product Details</a></td>";
    if($count%5==0) {
        echo "</tr> <tr>";
    }
        echo "</tr> ";
}
    $count++;
   }
```

Comment: Thank you again but this is not working :) your code put every product one under another, like this: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=10idv8i&s=8#.U3MpV_l_sVg

but i want to have this: http://i57.tinypic.com/6fzj4m.png